# T-SQL XML parsing: whitespace expected

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use an `update` statement for a column in my SQL Server table but I'm getting the following error message:

> Msg 9410, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 18
>   Whitespace expected

The XML code I'm trying to insert is much longer than the 30k character limit on this post but I've truncated it just as an example.

T-SQL

```
UPDATE Storefront_Product
SET
DynamicFormCode = '"<code version=""1.0"" type=""data"">&lt;data method=""BasicDynamicFormProduct"" version=""1.0""&gt;
  &lt;fields&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;textBox&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;dataType&gt;Decimal&lt;/dataType&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sacustomdimensions&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Custom Dimensions"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;maxLength&gt;&lt;/maxLength&gt;
        &lt;maxValue /&gt;
        &lt;minValue /&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;text&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US="""" /&gt;
        &lt;/text&gt;
        &lt;textMode&gt;SingleLine&lt;/textMode&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
        &lt;wrap&gt;True&lt;/wrap&gt;
      &lt;/textBox&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_seattype&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Seat Type"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""T-Cushion"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Extended Cushion"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Tight Cushion "" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
        &lt;/listItems&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
      &lt;/dropDownList&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_seatconstruction&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Seat Construction"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Standard (High Density foam with memory foam caps)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;1s&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;True&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Spring/Down"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Spring/Fiber"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Foam encased in Down"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;4&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""All Down"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;5&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
        &lt;/listItems&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
      &lt;/dropDownList&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_backtype&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Back Type"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Knife Back"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Box Back"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Tight Back"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;4&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Semi-attached Back"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;5&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Channel (vertical or horizontal)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;6&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Tufted"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""T-Back Knife Edge"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""T-Back Box "" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
        &lt;/listItems&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
      &lt;/dropDownList&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_backconstruction&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Back Construction"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Fiber"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;1&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""50/50 Blend"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""75/25 (75% Down/25% Fiber)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""90/10 (90% Down/10% Fiber)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;4&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""100% Down"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;5&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
        &lt;/listItems&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
      &lt;/dropDownList&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_armstyle&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Arm Style"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""English Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;1&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Modern English"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Track Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Track with nails"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;4&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Shelter Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;5&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Paris Club"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;6&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Modern Tuxedo"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;7&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Pleated Roll Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;8&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Panel Roll Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;9&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Pad Roll Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;10&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Saddle"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;11&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Key Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;12&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Runched Roll Arm"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;13&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Modern Slope"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;14&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Modern Scroll"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;15&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Panel"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;16&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Other"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;Other&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
        &lt;/listItems&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
      &lt;/dropDownList&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_legoptions&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Leg Options"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Wedge"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;1&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Turned"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Tapered"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Inside Tapered"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;4&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Bun"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;5&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Inside Tapered"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;6&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Acrylic"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;7&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Plinth Base"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;8&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Exposed wood base"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;9&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Metal"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;10&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""English Casters"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;11&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Round"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;12&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Splay"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;13&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Swivel (Applicable Chair Only)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;15&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Swivel Glider (Applicable Chair Only)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;16&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Swivel Rocker (Applicable Chair Only)"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;17&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Other "" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;Other &lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
        &lt;/listItems&gt;
        &lt;required&gt;False&lt;/required&gt;
        &lt;validatorText&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""*"" /&gt;
        &lt;/validatorText&gt;
      &lt;/dropDownList&gt;
    &lt;/field&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;dropDownList&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sa_designelements&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Design Elements"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""None"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;None&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Diamond Tuft"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;1&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Faux Tuft"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;2&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Square Tuft"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;3&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Buttonless Tuft"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;4&lt;/value&gt;
            &lt;selected&gt;False&lt;/selected&gt;
          &lt;/listItem&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;
              &lt;locale en-US=""Button Stuck"" /&gt;
            &lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;value&gt;5&lt;/value&gt;
t;id&gt;sa_weltplacement&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Welt Placement"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;
        &lt;listItems&gt;
          &lt;listItem&gt;

'
WHERE ProductID = 23
```

Comment: The double quotation marks seem to be causing the issue. CTRL+H "" with ".

Comment: You shouldn't use double quotes before the first opening `code` tag, and neither should you put extra doubles inside that tag. Oh, and it isn't closed. Where are you getting this invalid XML from?

Comment: This is not XML. Looks like XML encoding of an XML document.

Comment: Yes, i couldent post the entire xml it did have a closing "" but i had to erase half the XML because it was too much and didn't let me post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
declare @x xml;

set @x = '<code version="1.0" type="data">
&lt;data method=""BasicDynamicFormProduct"" version=""1.0""&gt;
  &lt;fields&gt;
    &lt;field&gt;
      &lt;textBox&gt;
        &lt;autoPostBack&gt;False&lt;/autoPostBack&gt;
        &lt;causesValidation&gt;False&lt;/causesValidation&gt;
        &lt;dataType&gt;Decimal&lt;/dataType&gt;
        &lt;id&gt;sacustomdimensions&lt;/id&gt;
        &lt;inputControlHeight&gt;&lt;/inputControlHeight&gt;
        &lt;inputControlWidth&gt;&lt;/inputControlWidth&gt;
        &lt;label&gt;
          &lt;locale en-US=""Custom Dimensions"" /&gt;
        &lt;/label&gt;

        Whatever you have here, everything works.
</code>';

select @x;
```

I have only removed the leading double quote, and extra doubles within the `/code` tag (and closed it in the end, of course).

There is something very wrong with the way this XML's string representation of yours is formed.